# How to execute .bat from .msi without including .bat in .msi itself?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My goal is to create a simple msi package that is supposed to do nothing but running a .bat script located in the same folder with the .msi. I don't need to copy any files on target machine or create folders, etc. I tried to use Wix 3.5 with vb-script which will run .bat i need. The vb-code itself works perfectly, but inside .msi it acts in a strange way - i can see a message box with the 'path', i got no errors, but script doesn't execute .bat.

```
 <Property Id="Launch">
  <![CDATA[
  Function Main()
    Set shell = CreateObject("WSCript.shell") 
    path = Session.Property("SourceDir") 
    MsgBox path
    shell.Run path & "sample.bat", 0, False
    Set shell = Nothing
    Main = 1
  End Function
  ]]>
</Property> 
<CustomAction Id="Die"
              VBScriptCall="Main"
              Property="Launch"                   
              Return="check"              
              Impersonate="yes"/>

  <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='Die' Before='RegisterProduct'> NOT Installed </Custom>  
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I also tried another way:

```
<Property Id='CMD'>cmd.exe</Property>
  <CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' Property='CMD' ExeCommand='[SourceDir]sample.bat' Return='check' Impersonate='yes'/>
```

But if I put 'notepad.exe' in property - everythings works great, when I use 'cmd.exe' console opens and closes without executing my sample.bat. In case of 'notepad.exe', it shows the content of 'sample.bat'. Could you guys help me out with this?

Comment: This seems redundant. Why not launch the BAT itself?

Comment: I need msi. This is a requirement. And I agree, this seems even a little bit stupid ;)

Comment: Since you agree, I'll say it's more the a little bit stupid.   Windows Installer is a declarative installation technology that supports rollback.   A .BAT file is the exact opposite of that.  To go outside of MSI and call a .BAT file is not solid engineering.

Comment: So, you don't know how to do that... that's all... a lot of stupid tasks emerge almost everyday, but they gotta be solved...

Comment: it is supposed to copy some stuff from one place to another, but the question is 'how to call it from .msi?' let's say arbitrary .bat... sample.bat deletes file from the directory where they all(.msi, .bat, file) are located

Comment: If it's all about copying files already present on a system, then [CopyFile element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm) can likely do that. If it's about removing files, then there's a [RemoveFile element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_removefile.htm). Custom actions is the last resort, and even in this case there are techniques to make them less evil than it can be. But running a bat file violates installation best practices. Behind stupid task there's often an original task, which can be completed the right way ;)

Comment: велике спасибі! but... there is nothing behind... trust me... i just have to do it this way, using .msi

Comment: Your requirement seriously is to have a blank .msi call a .bat file, or is it just to use an .msi? If it is the former, I would suggest just using an .msi the right way, and just say the .bat file gets launched, and whoever came up with the requirement would have no idea.

Comment: My requirement seriously is to have a blank .msi call a .bat file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was easy... Actually, everything was ok, but .bat itself was calculating relative paths from `%WinDir%\System32\` I just put `CD %~dp0` as the first line of my .bat and it started to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `/C` to ExeCommand

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' Property='CMD' ExeCommand='/C [SourceDir]sample.bat' Return='check' Impersonate='yes'/>
```

Comment: thanks! already tried this... i removed  "/c" to see that cmd.exe is really called. But it doesn't process my bat anyway...